# thread hang detector triggered by process stop or App Nap

Tags: c, macos

I have written a thread hang detector which prints some debugging output (backtraces, etc.) when some thread hangs unexpectedly. Each thread which wants to be watched registers itself in the hang-detector system, specifies some timeout (in my case 5 secs) and calls some `IAmAlife()` function frequently (in my case about every 1-10ms).

It works great. However, in some cases, I get false positives. E.g., when I `SIGSTOP` the process and resume it later, it gets triggered (for example, when attaching with a debugger like GDB/LLDB). And also rarely, when the process is just not doing much, just idling, I guess MacOSX' App Nap kicks in and it also triggers the hang detector.

How could I detect such system hangs? Looking at the processor time (`clock()`) doesn't help that much because if my app is in a deadlock, it will probably also not consume much (if any) processor time.

Answer (score 0):

So, the implementation might be a little complex, but the basic idea is simple: track the wall clock time and use that to figure a "grace period" to be added on to the amount of time that each thread can be late phoning home.

Use something like `gettimeofday()` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) to record the time when your watcher thread first starts. Each time it re-awakes, call `gettimeofday()` again, take the difference, and then subtract from *that* the amount of "processor time" elapsed. That gives you the rough "grace period" that you should grant, since it's time that your process was not running.

The only minor complexification arises because the grace period needs to be maintained separately for each of the threads you are watching. Since you clearly know enough to write threads, I'll assume that part is well within your ability :-).